# How do you reference a user's identities when making a REST call in an AAD B2C Custom Policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've been trying to reverse engineer how the normal API Connector for calling a REST API before creating a user works inside of Azure AD B2C.  I've been trying to figure out what `InputClaim` I need to provide in order to send over the normal `identities` payload that you see in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-user-flow#the-request-sent-to-your-api).

I've tried so many examples, but nothing goes far enough to show it.  Here's my current policy snippet.

```
...
<ClaimType Id="currentUserIdentities">
        <DisplayName>currentUserIdentities</DisplayName>
        <DataType>userIdentityCollection</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>currentUserIdentities</AdminHelpText>
        <UserHelpText>currentUserIdentities</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
...
<TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API">
          <DisplayName> Webhook</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <!-- Set the ServiceUrl with your own REST API endpoint -->
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">MY_URL_HERE</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_Username" />
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_Password" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentUserIdentities" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Claims parsed from your REST API -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="my_custom_claim" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

When I try to deploy this, I get:

```
Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy \"MY_POLICY_NAME\" of tenant \"MY_TENANT.onmicrosoft.com\".Technical profile 'REST-API' contains Input claim with id 'currentUserIdentities' that has an unsupported data type. The data types supported for this provider are 'Boolean, String, StringCollection, DateTime, Date, Int, Long, ObjectIdentity, ObjectIdentityCollection'
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was writing a custom `ClaimsTransformer` which generated the required JSON payload:

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateApiPayload" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" TransformationClaimType="givenName" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" TransformationClaimType="surname"/>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="identities.0.issuerAssignedId" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="identities.0.issuer" DataType="string" Value="{{ tenantId }}" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="apiRequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

This relies on the `{{ tenantId }}` template parameter, but it works!